# Animations with full alpha in Qt?

Tags: qt, animation, alphablending

Is there an animation format supported in Qt (using v4.4) that will support a full alpha channel?  GIF only has one-bit transparency, and I don't think Qt supports APNG.
Update: MNG seems to be supported, but that's even less popular than APNG!  Maybe SVG is my best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt supports SVG 1.2 Tiny as well as GIF and MNG. On a side-note, an animation API is being worked on which might be interesting for you;

http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2008/11/05/qt-animation-framework/
and
   http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Graphics/Kinetic

Answer (score 0):

Use the Animation codec with Quicktime, it supports a full alpha channel. Just chooose "Million of Colors+" when you select the Animation codec. You may need to enable "legacy codecs" option in the advanced settings.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing much of Qt, I will mention MNG and SVG, perhaps.